# Как подбирать соседний ZIP code США?

Tags: карты

у меня есть [ZIP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4) (это аналог индексов) , как можно подобрать соседний по территории, может есть готовые решения?
Может можно с [google maps api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start?csw=1) сделать такое, есть такой функционал у карт?